# How to Splitting APNG into png images and convert to animate gif by PHP

Tags: php, imagemagick, gd, apng

I want to convert `apng` to `gif` by `imagemagick`, but I don't know how to do

I see [Splitting APNG into png images with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746811/splitting-apng-into-png-images-with-php) I try it but it still no work in my image
I something like 
1.ezgif.com/apng-to-gif 
2.aconvert.com/image/apng-to-gif

```
<?php
function splitapng($data) {
  $parts = array();

  // Save the PNG signature   
  $signature = substr($data, 0, 8);
  $offset = 8;
  $size = strlen($data);
  while ($offset < $size) {
    // Read the chunk length
    $length = substr($data, $offset, 4);
    $offset += 4;

    // Read the chunk type
    $type = substr($data, $offset, 4);
    $offset += 4;

    // Unpack the length and read the chunk data including 4 byte CRC
    $ilength = unpack('Nlength', $length);
    $ilength = $ilength['length'];
    $chunk = substr($data, $offset, $ilength+4); 
    $offset += $ilength+4;

    if ($type == 'IHDR')
      $header = $length . $type . $chunk;  // save the header chunk
    else if ($type == 'IEND')
      $end = $length . $type . $chunk;     // save the end chunk
    else if ($type == 'IDAT') 
      $parts[] = $length . $type . $chunk; // save the first frame
    else if ($type == 'fdAT') {
      // Animation frames need a bit of tweaking.
      // We need to drop the first 4 bytes and set the correct type.

      $length = pack('N', $ilength-4);
      $type = 'IDAT';
      $chunk = substr($chunk,4);
      $parts[] = $length . $type . $chunk;
    }
  }

  // Now we just add the signature, header, and end chunks to every part.
  for ($i = 0; $i < count($parts); $i++) {
    $parts[$i] = $signature . $header . $parts[$i] . $end;
  }

  return $parts;
}
$filename = 'A.png';

$handle = fopen($filename, 'rb');
$filesize = filesize($filename);
$data = fread($handle, $filesize);
fclose($handle);

$parts = splitapng($data);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($parts); $i++) {
  $handle = fopen("part-$i.png",'wb');
  fwrite($handle,$parts[$i]);
  fclose($handle);
}


?>
```

Comment: Imagemagick does not handle APNG format

Comment: Really? But I saw my example website use it to convert

Comment: Run `convert -list format`. If you do not see APNG listed, then Imagemagick does not support it. It is not in my list nor on the web page at https://imagemagick.org/script/formats.php. As far as I know only PNG and MNG are supported

Comment: Is there any way can convert I really need QAQ

Comment: I do not think so with Imagemagick. You should search Google for other tools that might support it. However, if you think others have used it, then try with the command line or post a link to your APNG file and I will give it try. See apngdis under command line tools at http://littlesvr.ca/apng/. I found it by searching Google. I suspect there are other tools. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APNG

Comment: Correction: for apng to gif, see apng2gif at the link I provided just above.

Comment: I have saw this before ,but I need php or other web commend for user interface

Comment: You can run command line tools using PHP exec()

Comment: Let me try it thank you !

Answer (score 0):

i download [apng2gif](https://liquidtelecom.dl.sourceforge.net/project/apng2gif/1.7/apng2gif-1.7-bin-win32.zip)

and put it with my php with this code

```
<?php
header("Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8");


$link = substr($_POST["link"],0,-7).'_animation'.substr($_POST["link"],-7);


$linkname = substr($link,57,-32);
function link_code($link) {
  $headers = get_headers($link);
  return substr($headers[0], 9, 3);
}

$link_code = link_code($link);

if( $link_code == 200 ) {
file_put_contents($linkname.".png", fopen($link, 'r'));
  $x = iconv("cp950","UTF-8",shell_exec("apng2gif ".$linkname.".png ".$linkname.".gif"));
  echo "OKAY!";
}
else{
  echo "Nokay!";
}
?>
```

Can use AJAX POST link to do apng2gif and check is it alive or not 
thank fmw42 :D

Comment: Interesting. I did not know you could call shell_exec from with PHP Imagick. Glad to hear that it worked.

Comment: I try exec but feedback is Garbled i don't know how to do ,and i try shell_exec it work :D